# Using @import with Meteor

Tags: css, meteor

I'm using a css `@import` at the top of a stylesheet in my Meteor app. [MDN on @import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@import) says that the at-rule "must precede all other types of rules". In development, this works as expected, getting the font from Google. However in production, Meteor minimizes and concatenates all of the css, leaving my `@import` halfway down the file. I'm pretty sure that is the cause of this error I get (from the Firefox console):

```
[14:31:13.713] Unrecognized at-rule or error parsing at-rule '@import'. @ http://mysite.meteor.com/b8c40bfddcd8fb2703b86888363d3590feb986d3.css:17
```

Just in case it's not the problem I think it is, here's the rule:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900,400italic");
```

Has anybody run across this before and found a solution? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** it is now fixed and merged [(see the commit)](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/ca164d477dd364dd835c13f0b630ef04c126e54d)

---

*Previous answer:*

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/662).
You may want to try one of the alternative way of loading your font. Either by using another CSS file or by using javascript snippet provided by google :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Lato:400,700,900,400italic:latin' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); 
</script>
```

Comment: where exactly do you insert this?

Comment: It seems it's been corrected as per the comment on the issue I was linking to. But to answer your question, you would put that script in the head of your HTML file (or layout template). If you can test whether it's been corrected or not and share back, I could update my answer accordingly.